# Handling Promises properly with modular JS, can I refer to the same Promise.then() more than once?

Tags: javascript, webpack, promise, babeljs, es6-modules

This is my first Stack Overflow question and the first time I am building an App intended for public use. So forgive me if this question seems open to interpretation with many specific answers. Then again, I may be doing it all wrong!

I have a SPA that is making use of ES6 Modules with Webpack and transpiling using Babel.

There are some configurations/dependencies that I would like to be able to retrieve before certain parts of the program are initialised.

I am using jQuery.ajax that is wrapped in a Promise.

I have a module that is an IIFE. I am not sure this is good practice.

**iife.modular.promise.js**

```
export default (function(){
    // console.log('iife.modular.promise.js is invoked when app is parsed');

    function AjaxPromise(options) {

        // console.log ('Promise invoked, get response');

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            jQuery.ajax(options).done(resolve).fail(reject);
        });

    }

    return AjaxPromise({
        url: YOUR_URL,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          action: get_some_data
        }

    })
}())
```

I can then refer to it in another module.

**index.js**

```
import { default as modPromise } from './iife.modular.promise.js'
import { startApp } from './startApp.js'

modPromise.then( (response)=>{
  // return response data and do stuff.
  console.log(response)
  // EG
  // {
  //   success: true,
  //   data: "Hello World!"   
  // }

  // run application
  startApp()

});
```

This seems to work without any problems. However, the response from the promise(s) is needed to configure the initial **state** of Objects that are then referred to by different modules.

**puzzle.js**

```
import { default as modPromise } from'./iife.modular.promise.js'

class Puzzle {
    constructor(name, level, [args]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.puzzleSpec = [args]
    }

    isInit() {
        return `class initialised`;
    }
}

// closure
var puzzleInit;

modPromise.then( (response)=>{
  // my response data actually evaluates to an array
  let data = JSON.parse(response.data)
  // instantiate class.
  puzzleInit = new Puzzle ( ...data )
});

export { puzzleInit }
```

When the Promise is resolved the `puzzle.js` module is referencing the Puzzle object/class.

This is where I am perturbed. I am referencing the same Promise twice and invoking the `.then()` method in two separate modules.

`puzzle.js` to create a new instance of an object.

`index.js` for use as **control flow**. Don't run the app until the `puzzle.js` has been instantiated.

It doesn't seem to give any reference errors. I don't see why it should be a problem considering that the `iife.modular.promise.js` is only invoked once and returns a Promise object that can presumably be referred to many times.

It may be more effective to NOT use a modular IIFE returning a Promise. IE use a function declaration / expression that is only invoked once.

**onTheFly.modular.promise.js**

```
function onTheFly(){

    function AjaxPromise(options) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            jQuery.ajax(options).done(resolve).fail(reject);
        });

    }

    return AjaxPromise({
        url: YOUR_URL,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          action: get_some_data
        }

    })
}

export { onTheFly }
```

However, as each time `onTheFlyPromise()` is invoked in a module a new Promise/request would be made. Meaning that in order for the response.data to be shared across different modules the data would have to be stored in a dedicated module.

A possible way around this would be to use `Promise.all()`

#### many.promises.js

```
const manyPromise = function(args){

    return Promise.all(args);
}

export { manyPromise };
```

#### index.js

```
import { default as modPromise } from './modular.promise.js'
import { onTheFlyPromise } from './onTheFly.modular.promise.js'
// Promise All
import { manyPromise } from './manyPromise.js'

import { startApp } from './startApp.js'

const multiplePromises = manyPromise(modPromise, onTheFlyPromise() ); 

multiplePromises.then( (response)=>{
  // return response data from all promises and do stuff.
  console.log(response)

// EG [{ },{ }]

  // run application
  startApp()

});
```

All of these options seem to have potential and don't crash the app I am building.

I am not paying much attention to when the Promises are invoked and if they're asynchronous. I am presuming that because I am using jQuery.ajax that they're not truly asynchronous Promises?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). It's best to keep your question as **short** and **targeted** as possible, while still ensuring that it's complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a module that is an IIFE. I am not sure this is good practice.

It's unnecessary if you're using ES2015 modules as you've said you are. A module has its own scope.

> This is where I am perturbed. I am referencing the same Promise twice and invoking the .then() method in two separate modules.

That's absolutely fine, there's nothing wrong with that at all. It's perfectly valid for multiple consumers to use the same promise. They'll all see the same resolution value (or rejection reason). And it's not a problem at all if the promise is already resolved before the consumers call `then` or `catch`.

Note that your uses of the promise are missing rejection handlers. One of the rules of using promises is: Either handle errors (via `catch` or the second argument to `then`), or pass the result of `then` to something that *will* handle errors.

---

A note on:

```
import { default as modPromise } from './modular.promise.js'
```

Although that works, the more idiomatic way to import the default export is:

```
import modPromise from './modular.promise.js';
```

Comment: "Note that your uses of the promise are missing rejection handlers."  - Thanks for pointing this out. I've been reading about handling errors with promises (including your blog post on fetch API) and it's more complex than I first thought. Especially considering I am wrapping `jQuery.ajax` in ES6 Promise. I may abandon jQuery (Old Version) and go a different route. I placed the Promise in the IIFE so that it is invoked immediately. I guess I could export the Promise on its own for same effect.

Comment: @Cloudbop - :-) Yup, you could do `export default AjaxPromise(/*...*/);` Then anywhere you wanted to use that information: `import modPromise from "./iife.modular.promise.js"; modPromise.then(data => { /*...use the data...*/ }).catch(error => { /*...handle the fact there was an error...*/ });`

Comment: Crowder - Thanks for all your help. Accepted your answer.